# Is there some way to make amazon alexa read out anything sentby python

Tags: python, python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit

If i have an amazon alexa could I make it say anything via a python script.

For example if i had a python script to manage reminders and i would like to make alexa read a reminder at the time the reminder was set for.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a limited Alexa skills knowledge, take this with a grain of salt. You may have already found this page.

Here is a page on the Alexa Development website that describes adding a reminder capability to an Alexa skill. You might be able to leverage this with your Python script to accomplish what you are trying to do. This would be built inside an AWS Lambda function (using Python) so you could run the Python script you are trying to run.

[Alexa Reminders Docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-reminders-overview.html)

[AWS Lambda with Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html)